# Loading csv file into mysql on a server

Tags: mysql, csv

I know this type of question has been answered here, but none of them talk about how to load a csv file from local drive to a mysql db running on a remote server. Or a csv file stored on that remote server to mysql db on that server

I first ssh into the server and then enter the mycli client running on the server on terminal

Then I try to enter the following command to import the csv stored on a remote server location to a table data_3days inside user_db.

```
mysql user@11.4.135.139:user_db> LOAD DATA INFILE 'abc@11.4.135.139:/data/data_3days.csv'  
INTO TABLE data_3days  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

And it throws me access denied error.

```
 u"Access denied for user 'user'@'%' (using password: YES)")
```

Is there an option to enter password somewhere in this query?

Also how does one upload the local csv file to the mysql db on a remote server? I tried using SequelPro and it is very slow to upload a 600MB file.

Thanks

Comment: Use `LOAD DATA **LOCAL** INFILE ...`

Comment: what does Local Do? its for local file right? my file is already on the same host as u see

Comment: I put LOCAL. It gives this error now: 

u'The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

Comment: You need to start mysql with the `--local-infile` option in order for `LOCAL` to work. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_local-infile

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to pass a -p in the mysql call which should prompt you for the password prior to execution

```
mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u user -p
```